# Building my own garage door - are my plans going to work?

Tags: garage-door

I am building my own three section wood garage door. I can save a few grand this way and get exactly what I want. But, I also want to make sure I do it right. I have a local overhead door company that will provide me with all of the correct hardware if I supply details like weight and size.

I have drawn up construction plans which I think are pretty good. I need some kind souls to either validate my design (with some suggestions for improvements hopefully) or bring me back to earth.

I am using metal cross pieces (1-1/2" square tube) to keep the panels straight. I am not sure if I will use aluminum or galv steel. Depends on suggestions, price and weight.

Edit: I modified my plans based on feedback so far and put up images rather than the PDF. Note: You can right click the images and select Open in New Tab to see them in higher resolution.

I changed the galv flashing to keyed poplar strips. I am using redwood for the bottom because it will be in contact with the driveway. Any reason to use redwood instead of poplar for all of the edging?

[image: Garage Door Design]
[image: Details]

Thanks!
Brad

Comment: Any possibility of having the local overhead door company take a look at your designs?

Comment: Also note that not a lot of folks are going to trust you enough to download a PDF. If you want folks to look at your plans, post the plans as images. If you're not sure how to post photos, [here's a tutorial](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33).

Comment: I think that over time that galvanized flashing strip that you propose is going to give you nothing but trouble. It is almost for sure that it will get bent and distorted during the normal wear and tear that goes on as the door gets used. Bent out and it will look bad from the outside and bend in and it will interfere with the closing of the door.

Comment: @Tester101, Thanks, I can certainly try and run the plans by the company I am getting the hardware from - the worst they can say is no! I thought a single PDF would be better than several pics, but I get your security point.

Comment: @Michael. Good point, I was trying to come up with a more weight conscious way to keep the water out of the panel other than adding a solid wood edging like I did on the sides and bottom. But if I add the wood strip all around, I can resaw it thinner and mill a sort of t&g key between the panels.

Comment: Well, I built the door and it came out fantastic. I am installing it on Sunday if all goes well. When all done I will post final drawings, lessons learned and the like for anyone else crazy enough to attempt the same thing.

Comment: @BradMathews: Would you be able to post your final drawings, lessons learned, etc....I'm crazy enough to do the same.